# Spring Boot RequestBody with JSONObject

Tags: json, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I'm tring set my RestController to receive a json with another json inside of this (I don't now the structure of that second json)...
something like that:

```
{
    "field1":"value1",
    "jsonField":{
        "anotherField1":1,
        "anotherField2":0.2
    }
}
```

And my request class is like that:

```
public class Request {
    private String field1;
    private org.json.JSONObject jsonField;
}
```

But when i call my controller, `field1` is setted, but `jsonField` doesn't. It's setted only with `{}`

EDIT: This is the controller method:

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity postMethod(@RequestBody Request request) {}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define your own class for the `jsonField` object if you want it to be mapped automatically.

```
public class Request {
    private String field1;
    private JsonField jsonField;
}

public class JsonField {
    private Integer anotherField1;
    private Integer anotherField2;
}
```

---

If you don't know its structure beforehand, the approach will be different. You can use either a `Map`:

```
public class Request {
    private String field1;
    private Map<String, Object> jsonField;
}
```

or Jackson's `JsonNode` type

```
public class Request {
    private String field1;
    private JsonNode jsonField;
}
```

You can read about it more [here](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-mapping-dynamic-object).

Comment: but I don't now the strcture of the jsonField...

Comment: You need to state it in the question then, as it changes the approach.

Comment: @Teofilo, please see my updated answer.

Comment: The Map solution solved this. Thanks